# Cannot connect to docker daemon in intellij in ubuntu with snap

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, snapcraft

In Intellij Ultimate docker is not detected automatically.

I choose "create new", but i get the message, that i cannot connect to docker daemon at unix /var/run/docker.sock

i started docker with: `sudo snap docker start`

The file docker.sock exists.

i added permission like it is said in other posts: `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` and logged out and in again.

It does not help. What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. And I think that the snap package is not able to access `/var/run/docker.sock`
See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69565328/351758